# How do I make the p-value stationary even after transforming it?

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

I've tried diff.1:, diff.2: np.log, np.sqrt, np.cbrt but the p-value won't decrease.

diff seems to increase the p-values and np.sqrt and np.cbrt barely decreases the p-value.

is there a way to transform non-stationary values that don't become stationary even after transforming using the previously stated methods?

Here is the multivariate table:

| Time Period | EMT | DTS | BG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/04/2021 | 7.41 | 7.25 | 7.53 |
| 01/07/2021 | 7.71 | 7.52 | 7.46 |
| 01/10/2021 | 7.99 | 7.75 | 7.66 |
| 01/01/2022 | 8.10 | 7.83 | 7.73 |
| 01/04/2022 | 8.13 | 7.81 | 7.85 |
| 01/07/2022 | 7.70 | 7.50 | 7.50 |

```
data = pd.read_csv(inputfilepath, parse_dates=["Time Period"], index_col = "Time Period")

emtdata = data["EMT"]
dtsdata = data["DTS"]
bgdata = data["Bord Gais"]

    ad_fuller_result_4 = adfuller(bgdata)#.diff()[1:]
    
    print('BG')
    print(f'ADF Statistic: {ad_fuller_result_4[0]}')
    print(f'p-value: {ad_fuller_result_4[1]}')
    
    ad_fuller_result_7 = adfuller(dtsdata)#.diff()[1:])
    
    print('DTS')
    print(f'ADF Statistic: {ad_fuller_result_7[0]}')
    print(f'p-value: {ad_fuller_result_7[1]}')
    
    ad_fuller_result_8 = adfuller(emtdata)#.diff()[1:])
    
    print('EMT')
    print(f'ADF Statistic: {ad_fuller_result_8[0]}')
    print(f'p-value: {ad_fuller_result_8[1]}')
```

Here are the results:

```
EM&T
ADF Statistic: -0.15394452831058553
p-value: 0.9437932628988958

DTS
ADF Statistic: -0.0951392833474996
p-value: 0.9499205326778699

BG
ADF Statistic: -1.5425205176459476
p-value: 0.5123820913571207
```

---

Comment: not clear what the question is. Which pvalue?

Comment: @Josef I've updated the question to include the code and dataframe

Comment: plot the series, There might be a trend, structural breaks or similar that makes the series nonstationary even if it's not difference stationary.